# Overlaying two TextViews in a TableLayout using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

I created a TableLyout, that contains 3 Rows. Each of these rows contains 3 cells. Each Cell is supposed to contain two TextViews each. The Problem is that the TextViews are not overlaying at all. Here is the Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#aca49c"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_main"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bev_background_default"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_1"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bev_tile_default"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell_1_bg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bev_dis_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bev_tile_default"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell_2_bg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bev_dis_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bev_tile_default"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell_3_bg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bev_dis_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </TableRow>
...
```

Comment: I guess ur tableLayout's first child should be a Relativelayout rather than a LinearLayout."The Problem is that the TextViews are not overlaying at all"==> plz ellaborate?

Comment: Im so stupid. Yeah Setting it to Relative Layout Fixed it. Would you like to put it in the answer? Or should I remove the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess ur tableRow's first child should be a Relativelayout rather than a LinearLayout.